# Android Build Failure: Mismatch Between Kotlin 1.9.0 and Compose Compiler Extension 1.4.3

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm working on an Android project using Jetpack Compose and I have encountered a compatibility issue between Kotlin and Compose. Despite following the compatibility map and adjusting my versions accordingly, I'm still facing the same error. The error message I receive is:
This version (1.4.3) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.8.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.9.0 which is not known to be compatible.
My app gradle:

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
        viewBinding = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
```

and my project gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.4"
    }
```

in your build gradle app module.
Probably this version will fit well, if don't, you may need find another version  for the compiler extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
 composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.5.2'
    }
```

Change the kotlinCompilerExtentionVersion to 1.5.2.
For future reference, please check the below link for compatibility version information :
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin